# Accessing custom directive argument

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I have an issue with accessing the arguments of a directive I try to implement who is supposed to take an argument given by the client and filter some data depending of the arguments put in the directive. But I can not manage to access the argument of the directive even after I have the copy past the code from the documentation.
One of the weird think I have is the server require to add the `FIELD` location and I cannot find any mention of this location in the documentation so maybe I have a missing method I should implement to make it work but I cannot find it in the Apollo documentation.

I am on the version `2.6.4` for `apollo-server` and `apollo-server-koa` and `14.3.1` for `graphql-js`.

I put bellow an example of what I have.

thanks your help

```
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor, gql } = require("apollo-server")
const { defaultFieldResolver, GraphQLString, GraphQLList } = require("graphql")

const schema = gql`
  directive @myDirective(
    fields: [String]
  ) on FIELD_DEFINITION | FIELD

  type mainType { 
    anotherType: [AnotherType]
  }

  type AnotherType { 
    nestedType: [Object] @myDirective
  }
`

class MyDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
    field.args.push({
      name: "fields",
      type: GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
    })

    field.resolve = async (source, { fields, otherArgs }, context, info) => {
      const results = resolve.call(this, source, otherArgs, context, info)

      return results.filter(result =>
        fields.every(field => result.value !== field)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Arguments passed to the directive can be accessed with `this.args` as shown in the docs. However, you don't provide any arguments to your directive. If you did, it would look something like `nestedType: [Object] @myDirective@(fields: ["someField"])`

Comment: You are also missing an `await` before `resolve.call`, but that's unrelated to your question.